# É possível criar uma coluna em LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estou tentando transformar a seguinte query em LINQ

```
SELECT [nu_ano]
      ,[nu_mes]
      ,[id_projeto]
      ,[id_fase]
      ,'Financial Progress ("Competência")' as ds_categoria
      ,'Baseline' as ds_curva
       FROM [Alvarez_Marsal].[dbo].[Schedule_Status]
  where nu_mes = 12
```

A coluna ds_categoria e ds_curva são criadas na hora que o select é executado, pois não existem na tabela. É possível fazer a mesma coisa em LINQ?

Até o momento minha query em LINQ está assim:

```
var result = (from l in db.Schedule_Status
.Where(x => x.nu_mes == 12)
.Select(x => new Schedule_Status
 {
   nu_ano = x.nu_ano,
   nu_mes = x.nu_mes,
   id_projeto = x.id_projeto,
   id_fase = x.id_fase
 })
select l).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho esta *query* meio estranha, mas dá, seria isto o que deseja?

```
var result = (from l in db.Schedule_Status
    .Where(x => x.nu_mes == 12)
    .Select(x => new Schedule_Status {
        nu_ano = x.nu_ano,
        nu_mes = x.nu_mes,
        id_projeto = x.id_projeto,
        id_fase = x.id_fase,
        ds_categoria = "Financial Progress (\"Competência\")",
        ds_curva = "Baseline"
    })
    select l).ToList();
```

Não analisei se tem erros nela, apenas coloquei o que você quer.

Você deve preparar sua classe para ter esses campos. Ou usar um tipo anônimo:

```
var result = (from l in db.Schedule_Status
    .Where(x => x.nu_mes == 12)
    .Select(x => new {
        nu_ano = x.nu_ano,
        nu_mes = x.nu_mes,
        id_projeto = x.id_projeto,
        id_fase = x.id_fase,
        ds_categoria = "Financial Progress (\"Competência\")",
        ds_curva = "Baseline"
    })
    select l).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/AnonType.cs)

Comment: Seria isso sim, porém ao fazer isso retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:  'Schedule_Status' does not contain a definition for 'ds_categoria'

Comment: Eu achei que tinha, e como você quer colocar uma informação em um lugar que não tem ela?